# Flutter POST "File" datatype to API in dio body

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I would like to post "File" type data to API. The API receive File data type. I'm using dio like the code below, but every time I send the API Post request it give me error on the File type. It said:

> "JsonUnsupportedObjectError (Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of '_File')".

Can anyone explain it to me and tell me how to post file data type?

By the way I already tried to use MultipartFile but it giving me another error :)

```
Map body;
body = {
  'name': updateUserProfileBody.name,
  'image': updateUserProfileBody.image != null
      ? updateUserProfileBody.image!
      : null,
};

final response = await dio.post(
  MYAPILINK,
  data: jsonEncode(body),
  options: Options(
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $accessToken',
      },
      followRedirects: false,
      validateStatus: (status) {
        return status! < 500;
      }),
);
```

Comment: Try to encode the image to a base64 String, so you can add it to a JSON Object

Comment: Your problem is, you are trying to add binary data to a JSON object